# How do I parse this JSON object to get a list of recipe objects that I can then use?

Tags: java, json, android-studio, parsing

So I am incredibly new to Java and am needing help parsing a JSON response. I already have the method in which I am using to do so, but need help figuring out what exactly I am doing wrong.

I am using an API to retrieve recipes from a site. I am trying to get a list of recipes ("hits" in this case I assume?) that I can then show to the user.

Obviously I need the recipe name ("label" in this case) and other information. Can anyone help me?

Here is the response api response I am getting:

```
{
   "q": "chicken",
   "from": 0,
   "to": 10,
   "more": true,
   "count": 168106,
   "hits": [
      {
         "recipe": {
            "uri": "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#recipe_b79327d05b8e5b838ad6cfd9576b30b6",
            "label": "Chicken Vesuvio",
            "image": "https://www.edamam.com/web-img/e42/e42f9119813e890af34c259785ae1cfb.jpg",
            "source": "Serious Eats",
            "url": "http://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2011/12/chicken-vesuvio-recipe.html",
            "shareAs": "http://www.edamam.com/recipe/chicken-vesuvio-b79327d05b8e5b838ad6cfd9576b30b6/chicken",
            "yield": 4,
            "dietLabels": [
               "Low-Carb"
            ],
            "healthLabels": [],
            "cautions": [],
            "ingredientLines": [
               "1/2 cup olive oil",
               "5 cloves garlic, peeled",
               "2 large russet potatoes, peeled and cut into chunks",
               "1 3-4 pound chicken, cut into 8 pieces (or 3 pound chicken legs)",
               "3/4 cup white wine",
               "3/4 cup chicken stock",
               "3 tablespoons chopped parsley",
               "1 tablespoon dried oregano",
               "Salt and pepper",
               "1 cup frozen peas, thawed"
            ],
            "ingredients": [
               {
                  "text": "1/2 cup olive oil",
                  "weight": 108
               },
               {
                  "text": "5 cloves garlic, peeled",
                  "weight": 15
               },
               {
                  "text": "2 large russet potatoes, peeled and cut into chunks",
                  "weight": 532.5
               },
               {
                  "text": "1 3-4 pound chicken, cut into 8 pieces (or 3 pound chicken legs)",
                  "weight": 1587.5732
               },
               {
                  "text": "3/4 cup white wine",
                  "weight": 169.5
               },
               {
                  "text": "3/4 cup chicken stock",
                  "weight": 180
               },
               {
                  "text": "3 tablespoons chopped parsley",
                  "weight": 11.4
               },
               {
                  "text": "1 tablespoon dried oregano",
                  "weight": 6
               },
               {
                  "text": "Salt and pepper",
                  "weight": 16.46384
               },
               {
                  "text": "Salt and pepper",
                  "weight": 8.23192
               },
               {
                  "text": "1 cup frozen peas, thawed",
                  "weight": 134
               }
            ],
            "calories": 4055.7632,
            "totalWeight": 2765.59,
            "totalTime": 60,
            "totalNutrients": {},
            "totalDaily": {},
            "digest": []
         },
         "bookmarked": false,
         "bought": false
      },
      {
         "recipe": {
            "uri": "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#recipe_8275bb28647abcedef0baaf2dcf34f8b",
            "label": "Chicken Paprikash",
            "image": "https://www.edamam.com/web-img/e12/e12b8c5581226d7639168f41d126f2ff.jpg",
            "source": "No Recipes",
            "url": "http://norecipes.com/recipe/chicken-paprikash/",
            "shareAs": "http://www.edamam.com/recipe/chicken-paprikash-8275bb28647abcedef0baaf2dcf34f8b/chicken",
            "yield": 4,
            "dietLabels": [],
            "healthLabels": [],
            "cautions": [],
            "ingredientLines": [],
            "ingredients": [],
            "calories": 3033.2012,
            "totalWeight": 1824.6125,
            "totalTime": 0,
            "totalNutrients": {},
            "totalDaily": {},
            "digest": []
         },
         "bookmarked": false,
         "bought": false
      },
      {
         "recipe": {
            "uri": "http://www.edamam.com/ontologies/edamam.owl#recipe_584ac5e486c088b3c8409c252d7f290c",
            "label": "Chicken Gravy",
            "image": "https://www.edamam.com/web-img/fd1/fd1afed1849c44f5185720394e363b4e.jpg",
            "source": "Martha Stewart",
            "url": "http://www.marthastewart.com/332664/chicken-gravy",
            "shareAs": "http://www.edamam.com/recipe/chicken-gravy-584ac5e486c088b3c8409c252d7f290c/chicken",
            "yield": 6,
            "dietLabels": [],
            "healthLabels": [],
            "cautions": [],
            "ingredientLines": [],
            "ingredients": [],
            "calories": 1092.3606,
            "totalWeight": 1590.8628,
            "totalTime": 270,
            "totalNutrients": {},
            "totalDaily": {},
            "digest": []
         },
         "bookmarked": false,
         "bought": false
      },
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {}
   ]
}
```

This is currently the method I am using to parse the JSON object:

```
public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        final String myResponse = response.body().string();
                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            private Object Date;

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                String jsonData = myResponse;
                                query_result.setText(myResponse);
                                Log.d("response5", myResponse);
                                //JSONObject jsonData1 = new JSONObject(myResponse);
                                JSONObject Jobject = null;
                                try {
                                    Jobject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
                                    Log.d("jobject", Jobject.toString());
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                JSONArray Jarray = null;
                                try {
                                    Jarray = Jobject.getJSONArray("hits");
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject object;
                                    try {
                                        object = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                                        try {
                                            JSONArray Recipe = object.getJSONArray("recipe");
                                        }catch (JSONException e){
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                        for (int j = 0; j < Jarray.length(); j++){
                                            JSONObject object2 = null;
                                            try {
                                                object2 = Jarray.getJSONObject(j);
                                                String Name = object2.getString("label");
                                                String Photo = object2.getString("image");
                                                Log.d("rec_query", " " + Photo);
                                            }catch (JSONException e){
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                                Log.d("response6:", e.toString());
                                            }
                                        }

                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });

            return null;
        }
    }
```

***NOTE THE {} {} are just different recipes...it wouldnt fit the whole response***

At the moment, when I try to print my variables in the Log, I am getting a message that says the variable is empty (the variable that i used to store the different recipes/"hits".

Answer (score 1):

Your response seems incomplete, it's not in the correct JSON format，Provide the right format and I'll try to help you

Comment: This is the raw response I retrieved from the API. Is there something else I can do? What is missing?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out what the issue was. I will edit my post to include the whole response.

Comment: A string in JSON format must have a complete '{}' [] 'to indicate that it is an array or an object, starting with' {', or' ['

Comment: Should be fixed now

Comment: any ideas? I recently fixed the response. Note that the empty {} are just more recipes. I couldnt fit the whole response because it was too many characters

Answer (score 0):

```
     String s = "{\n" +
            "    \"a1\":\"1\",\n" +
            "    \"b2\":[\n" +
            "        {\n" +
            "            \"b21\":\"vb21\"\n" +
            "        },\n" +
            "        {\n" +
            "            \"b22\":\"vb22\"\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "    ]\n" +
            "}";
    JSONObject object = JSON.parseObject(s);
    String vb21 = object.getJSONArray("b2").getJSONObject(0).getString("b21");
```

like this,and neep to import com.alibaba.fastjson 
But i dont`t know if you can use fastjson

Comment: {
    "a1":"1",
    "b2":[
        {
            "b21":"vb21"
        },
        {
            "b22":"vb22"
        }
    ]
}